# How to do ma and loess normalization in R?

Tags: r, statistics, normalization, regression, loess

Attempting to do loess on two variables `x` and `y` in R using MA normalization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MA_plot) like this:

```
> x = rnorm(100) + 5
> y = x + 0.6 + rnorm(100)*0.8
> m = log2(x/y)
> a = 0.5*log(x*y)
```

I want to normalize x and y in such a way that the average `m` is 0, as in standard MA normalization, and then back-calculate the correct x and y values. First running loess on MA:

```
> l = loess(m ~ a)
```

What is the way to get corrected `m` values then? Is this correct?

```
> mc <- predict(l, a)
# original MA plot
> plot(a,m)
# corrected MA plot
> plot(a,m-mc)
```

not clear to me what `predict` actually does in the case of `loess` objects and how it's different from using `l$residuals` in the object `l` returned by `loess` - can someone explain?
finally, how can I back calculate new `x` and `y` values based on this correction?

Comment: gogling leads me to `library(affy)`, it contains `normalize.loess` and  `ma.plot` functions. Why not to use this package for example at least to control your result?

Comment: @agstudy: that's fine but this is simple enough that it should be implementable with `loess` no need for the overhead of an extra package. I want to understand how the loess fitting works in R without relying on packages

Answer (score 0):

First, yes, your proposed method gets the corrected `m` values.

Regarding the predict function: yes, `l$residuals` , `m - fitted(l)` , and `m -
 predict(l)` all give the same result: the corrected m values. However, the `predict` function is more general: it will take any new values as input. This is useful if you want to use only a subset of the data to fit the loess, and then predict on the totality of the data (for example, when using spiked-in standards).

Finally, how can you back calculate new `x` and `y` values based on this correction? If you transform your data into log-space, by creating two new variables `x1 <- log2(x)` and `y1 <- log2(y)`, it becomes easier to see. Since we're in log-space, calculating `m` and `a` is simpler:

- `m <- x1 - y1`
- `a <- (x1 + y1)/2`

Now, for correcting your data based on the fitted loess model, instead of updating the `m` variable by your `mc` correction, you can update `x1` and `y1` instead. Set:

- `x1 <- x1 - mc / 2`
- `y1 <- y1 + mc / 2`

This update has the same effect as updating `m <- m - mc` (because `m` will be recomputed as the difference between the updated `x1` and `y1`) and has no effect on the `a` value.

To get your corrected data out, transform them by returning `2^x1` and `2^y1`.

This is the method as used by the authors of the normalize.loess function in affy package, as originally described here (and includes the capability to cyclically look at all pairs of variables as opposed to a single pair in this case):  http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/limma/html/normalizeCyclicLoess.html